# Docker Spring MySQL Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, docker, hibernate

I'm creating a Docker image for my Spring app, but there is an issue with the MySQL database tables creation, the DB users is created but it's empty. Please help me with this because it takes too much time.

This is the docker-compose file

```
   version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - spring-net
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
      - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
      - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create  # Set this property for Hibernate table creation
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
#      - ./src/main/resources/applicationContext-jdbc.xml:/app/applicationContext-jdbc.xml

  mysqldb:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - spring-net
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users
      #   MYSQL_USER: root
      #   MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
#    volumes:
#      - ./src/main/resources/applicationContext-jdbc.xml:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/applicationContext-jdbc.xml

networks:
  spring-net:
```

and the Dockerfile itself

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-8 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mvn clean package

FROM tomcat:9.0.84-jre8
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY --from=build /app/target/spring-rest-hibernate.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

for my app the DB configuration is made in the applicationContext-jdbc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa">
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.javasavvy.spring" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.javasavvy.spring.services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.javasavvy.spring.dao" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users" />
<!--        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/userM?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />-->
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="passworda" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa-unit" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>-->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```